# Giving JQuery answers to Questions not tagged JQuery

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers, not-an-answer

I have asked a number of questions with the JavaScript tag, and in said questions, I deliberately did not add the JQuery tag because I was not able to use JQuery in my code. I have seen a number of questions like this, and to me it is frustrating. I have had to take to adding an extra note at the bottom that specifically asks that no JQuery answers be given, and yet I still get JQuery answers. If I wanted to/was able to use JQuery for my code, I would've tagged it with JQuery. Why don't people respect the distinction between the two? I know JQuery is a javascript library, but still it's not the same thing. 
Is there a better way to prevent unwanted JQuery answers?

I've tried to explain in comments that I can't accept a JQuery answer, and I've gotten some hostile/negative responses. What Can I do to emphasize that I DO NOT WANT JQuery answers? Could there theoretically be something implemented into stack overflow that would prevent JQuery from being used in snippets for questions tagged javascript, with no JQuery tag?

Comment: [I see you want to jquery..](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19492#19492)

Comment: @Raystafarian what'd'ya mean?

Comment: I voted to close this question since it only contained jQuery a measly 14 times. Please consider editing your question to include more jQuery.