# Are the rules for answering questions rigid or flexible?

Tags: discussion, support, answers

I was wondering when I answered a question where the OP was asking for some query related to [openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/openpyxl).

As the OP was facing issues, I thought of supporting the OP by suggesting an analogous method for achieving the same.

I had a consent from the OP as well where it had permitted me answering the question using another methodology.

But others who had visited the question had told me that I cannot answer that way as it is not considered as an answer here.

You can visit and see the whole thing here: *[Can someone explain why this happens when using openpyxl 2.6.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56489346/can-someone-explain-why-this-happens-when-using-openpyxl-2-6-2/)*

The link to my answer is:  *https://stackoverflow.com/a/56489601/9396051*, and the comments could be viewed below.

I want to know whether SO has that sort of strict rules for the people trying to help others. Can these rules be bend for the person trying to help?

Why cannot one answer the question so that the OP's solution become simple for them?

Please let me know.

Comment: The OP will always say "yes" if you promise him a solution, so that's not much to go by.  Nothing wrong with alternative approaches, pretty desirable actually, but the commenters helpfully point out that there are several holes in the approach you proposed.  You might not like what happens when the next thousand googlers find that question and want to solve the same problem.

Answer (score 9):

Questions which ask about a problem with a specific library should only be answered with that library/language. Answers with other technologies are not useful, because people searching for the same problem expect to find answers for that technology and not for something else.

The same goes for programming languages. When the OP asks about a Java problem, an answer in Python is not useful.

There is an exception though: When the question is something like "How can I do X in library Y", and doing X in Y is impossible, then answers like "Doing X in Y is not possible, but you can use library Z and do ...".

There are related discussion about answering JavaScript questions with jQuery, for example, [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303654/giving-jquery-answers-to-questions-not-tagged-jquery).

Comment: I can understand that sir. But the problem was not of programming language. The language was same. I have only suggested that there is certain way out which is more flexible. The OP did not have issues but the people around had a lot to say as you can see.

Comment: I would be a bit willing to discuss about the usefulness if the question would at least ask how to rename the workbook. But the question asks why a specific API function doesn't behave as expected. Your answer isn't even related to that.

Comment: So that means I have to be on topic even if it is not worthy to go with some method. I cannot even suggest about something. Is that the meaning of usefulness? And thats why you downvoted I guess.

Comment: @AmazingThingsAroundYou: You can suggest better solutions, but you also have to answer the question. And this **only** works on question that ask how to do something. **Not** on questions that ask about why an API function doesn't do what it is expected to do.

Comment: Alright I have removed the answer. I won't torture the OP with my answer. Thank you for the discussion.

Comment: You can wait for a few days and then check again how my answer is voted. I'm just one voice here and voting will show if my opinion is accepted by the rest of the community.

Answer (score 4):

There is not a single answer to "are the rules for answering questions rigid or flexible?", because some rules are more flexible than others. Your question, however, is mainly about a specific rule: that answers should directly address the question asked by the OP. That rule indeed is on the stricter side of the spectrum. It is so because the audience of any Q&A goes beyond the question OP, including any future readers who find it through search results. If, for instance, those readers are specifically looking for a solution to a concrete problem using Openpyxl, it is not very likely they will be interested in a digression about how it might be done using Pandas.

One kind of situation in which there is some more flexibility with directly addressing the question as asked is when the OP is clearly going into a dead end with the approach presented in the question, or when the framing of the question doesn't focus on the most relevant part of the problem ([the "XY problem" scenario](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)). That, however, doesn't apply to the question we are talking about, as there is nothing fundamentally problematic with using Openpyxl instead of Pandas for the task set out in the question.